# What's the difference between state.path and route.path in angular2

Tags: angular

In reading angular2 documnet, I get confused in CanLoad param,

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

In CanLoad section, it uses `/${route.path}`, when CanActivate uses state.url.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
}

canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
  let url = `/${route.path}`;

  return this.checkLogin(url);
}
```

What's the difference? Why doesnot use route.path directly, but wrapped with `/${}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference? Why doesnot use route.path directly, but wrapped with `/${}` ?

```
`/${route.path}`;
```

is just using string interpolation to prefix the `route.path` with a `/`

`${route.path}` is replaced by the result of `route.path`. 
If `route.path` returns `foo/bar` the result will be `/foo/bar`

Comment: Yes, that's basically the same.